# C# add to class in another DLL

Tags: c#, class, extending-classes

...is it possible?

For example, can I add this simple function...

```
public static double Deg2Rad(double degrees) {
    return Math.PI / 180 * degrees;
}
```

...to the `Convert` class?
So (using the default..."usings") you can call

```
double radians = Convert.Deg2Rad(123);
```

Can this be done?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't, but you can add an Extension method to `double` and call it like

```
double x = 180.0;
double y = Math.Cos( x.Deg2Rad() );
double z = Math.Sin( 0.5.Pi() );
```

in an static class add the following extension method:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static double Deg2Rad(this double angle)
    {
        return Math.PI*angle/180.0;
    }

    public static double Pi(this double x)
    {
        return Math.PI*x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Accepted, also is there a way to make this apply for ints too without rewriting it with int?

Comment: You can cast it as double: `x = ((double)i).Pi()` but it is ugly. Just go ahead and write extensions for the types you want. You can place the extensions in different namespaces, so depending what `using` statement you use, different extensions will be available.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. You could use extensions if `Convert` weren't `static`, but no.

You could add an extension to `double` though, using the `this` keyword:

```
public static double Deg2Rad(this double degrees) {
    return Math.PI / 180 * degrees;
}
```

And use it like so:

```
double radians = (123D).Deg2Rad();
```

You'll have to put your method in a `static` class for it to work, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort of get what you want.  C# has "Extension Methods".  This allow you to add methods to another class, even if that class is in another assembly that you do not have the source code for.  However, you cannot add static functions to another class.  You can only add instance methods.

For more information, see [MSDN Extensions Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

No you can't, but you don't really need to - you can just declare your own static class instead, for example:

```
public static class MyConvert
{
    public static double Deg2Rad(double degrees) 
    {
        return Math.PI / 180 * degrees;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
double radians = MyConvert.Deg2Rad(123);
```

(Obviously `MyConvert` is a rubbish name, but you get the idea).

The only difference between the above and having the method on the system `Convert` class is that if its on the `Convert` class it looks like a built-in function, but you are going to struggle to convince me thats actually a good thing (I like to know when I'm calling framework code vs code maintained internally).

Answer (score -1):

Apart from what has been said here, there is also another option which is [Partial classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (this won't apply to Convert).

If the class is declared partial, then you can add menthods via another partial class, even if it's in another assembly (DLL).

But, again, the class has to be originally declared partial for that to work.

Comment: I know this is old, but just to be sure others don't get misled by this, I am downvoting and posting a link showing that partial classes cannot be used across of assemblies: http://stackoverflow.com/a/647459/16241