# Partial Class Confliction in Asp.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Data Models--created by Linq2SQL Class Diagram tool--in another assembly (Class Library Project) and I created another one

Here it is:

```
public partial class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);
    private int _ID;
    private string _FirstName;
    private string _LastName;
    private string _Email;
    private System.DateTime _DOB;
    private string _PhoneNumber;
    private bool _Activated;
    private bool _Suspended;
            //..
}
```

In my Web Project, I created another one with the same name as partial:

```
  public partial class Customer
  {
    //It will have MetadataTypeAttribute for validation.
  }
```

I am using same namespace for them so they should be fine however, when I make View as Strongly typed using Customer object:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Customer>" %>
```

I get this error:

> [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGlobalScopeAttribute()] Line
>   184:    public class views_register_registrationformcontrol_ascx :
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl {

Detailed Error Screen Shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlZ4p.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot have partial classes across multiple assemblies:

Check this answer

[Is it possible to have two partial classes in different assemblies represent the same class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/647385/1268570)

Comment: Well I think this is the answer. Thanks.