# Casting from child to parent class to a method in dll

Tags: c#

In the exe have a child and base classes defined as follows. The partial classRootX is defined in multiple files of the exe.

```
namespace X
{
    public partial classRootX
    {

    }

    public class child : classRootX
    {
         A a = new A(( classRootX ) this );
    }
}
```

In a dll

```
using X;
namespace Y
{
   public class A
   {
       public A(ClassRootX root)
       {
       }
   }
}
```

get a compiler error

> "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'classRootX [....\file.cs(79)]' to 'classRootX [....\xxx.dll]'

Any suggestions for a fix?

Comment: Missed a using Y; before namespace X

Comment: You can't have `classRootX` _defined_ in both if you want to include on in the other. Then the compiler _will_ get confused. Better approach is to have two separate names.

Comment: [You cannot have partial classes spread across multiple assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/647385/216074).

Comment: By "DLL" do you mean an already built dll file? Or a class library project in the solution? Also note that `classRootX != ClassRootX`. And the dll references your main exe project? That doesn't seem fine to me.

Comment: Update the post to clarify that classRootX is not defined in dll.  Yes dll means a already built dll file / assembly

Answer (score 0):

You can't make the static dll depend on the code you are writing.

The dll knows `ClassRootX` as it was when it was compiled. It doesn't know your current `ClassRootX`. What if the dll does `root.SomeProperty` and your code doesn't have it? The dll would have a "compilation error", which makes no sense.

You shouldn't have two projects reference each other, that produces a circular reference. If you need some flexibility in what class A received, you can use an interface, defined in the dll, and then make `classRootX` implement it.